# Compare two (py) spark sql dataframes and conditionally select column data while keeping joined column

Tags: python, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two sql dataframes with identical schema with 500+ columns:

```
df_A
+----+---+---+...
| id | A | B |...
+----+---+---+...
| w1 | 0 | 1 |...
+----+-- +---+...
| w2 | 1 | 1 |...
+----+-- +---+...
| w3 | 0 | 1 |...
+----+-- +---+...

df_B
+----+---+---+...
| id | A | B |...
+----+---+---+...
| w1 | 0 | 1 |...
+----+-- +---+...
| w2 | 0 | 1 |...
+----+-- +---+...
| w3 | 0 | 1 |...
+----+-- +---+...
```

I would like to return a dataframe such that when df_A. is 1 then 1 otherwise the value of df_B.

---

The below code is able to return the column comparison correctly but I cannot add the id column.  Any suggestions?

```
results = df_A.alias("a").join(df_B.alias("b"), "id").selectExpr(["case when b.`{0}` = 1 then 1 else a.`{0}` end as `{0}`".format(yy) for yy in df_b.columns[1:]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you just want to also select `"Master_ID"` in `selectExpr()`. However because the rest of the args are built up as a list, you cant' just also pass it next to the list. You'll want to add it to the list, like:

```
select_exprs = [...]
select_exprs.append("Master_ID")
....selectExpr(select_exprs)
```

Or more completely:

```
column_select = ["Master_ID"]
select_expr = ["case when b.`{0}` = 1 then 1 else a.`{0}` end as `{0}`".format(yy) for yy in prediction_df.columns[1:]]
column_select = column_select + select_expr
results = wide_pred_df.alias("a").join(prediction_df.alias("b"),"Master_ID").selectExpr(column_select)
results.printSchema
```